# VBA Single Loop should loop for 1000 rows but stops at the fourth row

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub LoopingAccr()

Dim i As Integer
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String

For i = 6 To 1000

fPath = "*path address"
fName = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fPath & fName
Workbooks(fName).Worksheets("Gross Profit Margin").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Range("C31:I31").Copy
Workbooks("Macro Test").Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(fName).Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i

End Sub
```

When I try to run the above code, an error message appears after four rows, but currently I have 81 rows of data. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: This is the result that i get]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why not step through the code with VBA's builtin debugger to see what's happening? You can then see what's happening as well inspect the variable values.

Comment: First; are you looping through 994 workbooks? If not then change your "i" to equal 81.   Second; This is just a guess, since you don't provide a lot of information, i think the error appears after you open your fifth workbook, and try to activate `Worksheets("Gross Profit Margin").Activate`, you  probably don't have the worksheet in that workbook. You need to loop through all the workbooks and before you activate the worksheet,  check if that worksheet is in the workbook, if not go to the next workbook.

Answer (score 0):

try a similar code to this:

```html
Sub LoopingAccr()

Dim i As Integer
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
dim sh as worksheet

' no need to set in every cicle
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
For i = 6 To 1000

fPath = "*path address"
' I hope that path address is ended with application.pathseparator
fName = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fPath & fName

' nono: Workbooks(fName).Worksheets("Gross Profit Margin").Activate
 for each sh in Workbooks(fName).Worksheets
 if sh.name="Gross Profit Margin" then
 Workbooks(fName).sh.Activate

Range("C31:I31").Copy
Workbooks("Macro Test").Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
end if: next sh


Workbooks(fName).Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i
  
End Sub
```